# C GUI, with a C++ backbone?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, ubuntu-9.04

I have a simple (and also trivial) banking application that I wrote in C++. I'm on ubuntu so I'm using GNOME (GTK+). I was wondering if I could write all my GUI in C/GTK+ and then somehow link it to my C++ code. Is this even possible?

**Note:** I don't want to use Qt or GTKmm, so please don't offer those as answers.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: When I say it's trivial I just mean that it's something that I'm doing for fun, not for a job or anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a very easy thing to do.  All you have to do is expose some of the C++ functions as "extern C" so that the event handlers and callbacks in your UI code can call them.

In the case that you can't change the existing C++ source - no problem.  just write a C++ shim for your UI, extern those functions, and call backend functions from there.

Comment: @Ben Collins: Can you provide some examples on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  See here: http://pastebin.com/f364909f2.  Also, a good and brief reference for this kind of thing is here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not, with appropriate [extern "C"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6) usage so your C code can call into C++.  Now, granted, you're probably making it a bit harder on yourself, but it's theoretically sound.

Answer (score 0):

Like others propose you can write a C wrapper for your C++ library. But you can also write the front-end in C++, even if you only use the C subset. I can understand if you don't like the language mixing, but it is the easiest way, because you save the time to write the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can just compile your GTK/C code as C++ without using GTKmm, and use the C++ code natively.

Most sane C libraries can be used from native C++ code, and GTK+ is fundamentaly a C library.